# Why accessing a sparse matrix is costly?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a 1034_by_1034 sparse matrix (`scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix`), which basically represents the adjacency matrix of a graph. I want to check if some elements are ones or not. But I found this to be a very slow operation. Before the `if statement` the code runs in **11** seconds, but when I enable the if check, it takes **40** seconds!

Here's my code snippet:

```
target = list()
for edge_id in edges_ids:
    v1_label, v2_label = from_edgeID_to_vertix_labels(edge_id) #fast
    v1_index = g.get_v_index(v1_label) #fast
    v2_index = g.get_v_index(v2_label) #fast

    #if the following chunk is enabled, it becomes slow!     
    if A[v1_index, v2_index] == 1:
        target.append(1)
    else:
        target.append(0)
g.target = target
```

Comment: Maybe the slow part is appending to the list? Replace both `target.append()` lines with `pass` and see how long it takes.

Comment: What's the fill factor of the matrix?

Comment: @Claudiu I did, but the time got reduced only to a minor factor like 1 or 2 secs.

Comment: @Emmet there's no filling for the matrix here. Just accessing it.

Comment: @AlexTwain: No, I mean the fill-factor of the matrix (ratio of number of non-zeros (nnz) to total matrix size, in this case 1,069,156), not *fill-in* due to any algorithm.

Comment: Try a `dok` matrix.  That uses a Python dictionary, which gives efficient access to randomly selected elements.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is quite likely to be the fact that fetching a single value from a sparse matrix in CSR (or CSC form), given indices (*i*, *j*), is very expensive. Algorithms for these sparse matrix representations aren't usually designed to do that: they're designed to use the indices they find as they go through the arrays sequentially.

In CSR, when you look up a row, you effectively get an array of column indices and the corresponding values. If you're fetching a single value, you have to do a linear search through the little array of column indices (unsorted in general) to see if it's there (otherwise the value is zero); if found, you then pick the value out of the value array and return it. It might look a bit like this ad-hoc *C* (this is intended to be *illustrative*):

```
/* Obviously silly CSR matrix typedef */
typedef struct sparse_s {
    int    row[nnz+1];
    int    col[nnz];
    double value[nnz];
} sparse_s;


double spGetValue(sparse_s const* s, int i, int j)
{
    int k;

    for(k=s->row[i]; k<s->row[i+1]; k++) {
        if( j == s->col[k] ) {
            return s->value[k];
        }
    }
    return 0.0;
}
```

So, if you were to average 10 elements on every row, you have to search through a ten element array for every access. This is much less of a problem for algorithms like SpMV that use the column indices as they find them. If you implemented SpMV like dense MM, fetching every value, it would be horribly horribly slow even if you had some oracular magic way of skipping the zeros. If you think that's bad, *inserting* an element into a CSR/CSC matrix is so viciously expensive that it's (almost) never done.

In short, you might get better results by either reorganizing your code so that you're iterating over the three vectors of the CSR matrix directly or using a different sparse matrix representation for this particular problem.

It might well be something more “Pythoney”, but I wouldn't expect your code to perform well even in a best-case scenario in *C* if the matrix representation and access method were retained.

Answer (score -1):

In this case, you may be better off using a nested defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict
A = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(int))
# Example of how to set an element in the adjacency matrix:
A[1][2] = 1
```

However, that does not support any of the matrix manipulations offered by numpy or scipy, but it should be fast for that particular use case.